# what change is necessary to make this code detect multiple faces rather than only one

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, dlib

I am new to openCV and dlib modules. I have trying to make this code to detect multiple faces but only the first face is detected.

```
  import numpy as np
  import argparse
  import imutils
  import dlib
  import cv2
  from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

  def rect_to_bb(rect):
      x = rect.left()
      y = rect.top()
      w = rect.right() - x
      h = rect.bottom() - y
     return (x, y, w, h)

 image = cv2.imread("image.jpg")
 image = imutils.resize(image, width=500)
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()

 rects = detector(image, 1)

 fname = "image.jpg".split('/')[-1]
 name, ext = fname.split('.')
 new_ext="png"

 for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
       (x, y, w, h) = rect_to_bb(rect)

       fname = '{}_{}.{}'.format(name, i, new_ext)
       clone = image.copy()
       cv2.rectangle(clone, (x, y), (x + w , y + h), (0, 255, 0), 1)
       startX = x
       startY = y - 15 if y - 15 > 15 else y + 15
       cv2.putText(clone, str(i), (startX, startY),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
       roi = image[y:y + h, x:x + w]
       cv2.imshow("Seprate Faces", roi)
       cv2.imwrite(fname, roi)
       cv2.imshow("Detected Faces", clone)
       cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Your response is appreciated! ! thanks

Comment: do you get each face individually but you want all together in one image? Move clone = image.copy() out of the loop (before) and imshow and waitKey out of the loop (after).

Comment: @Micka, it kinda worked. it detects two faces now but can't save the two face. it still save only one face

Comment: Man, it worked thanks for that. It saved the two faces but it show only one face while running but it helped. Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to submit your grayscale to the detector:

```
rects = detector(gray, 1)
```

Comment: that doesn't help